# Logging in is not working?

Tags: javascript, authentication

Dear Stackoverflowers,

For school I am making a simple sort of social media website and I need to show that you for instance can log in. I am not that experienced with Javascript so I tried to combine my knowledge and information I could find on youtube and w3school and came with this. Only when I press the login button it's not doing anything (as far as I can see).

PS: I know the website is really ugly, but it's about that some specific features are working :3

```js
var count= 2;
 
function validate(){
 
    var username = document.login.username.value;
    var password = document.login.password.value;
    var valid= false;
    var usernameArray = ["Gdp", "Hekman", "Koning", "ErikHekman", "ThijsWaardenburg", "Ronald", "RonaldVanEssen" ];
    var passwordArray = ["Gdp123", "Hekman123", "Koning123", "ErikHekman123", "ThijsWaardenburg123", "Ronald123", "RonaldVanEssen123"];
 
    for (var i = 0; i < usernameArray.length; i++)
 
{
 
    if ((username == usernameArray[i]) && (password == passwordArray[i]))
    {
        valid = true;
        break;
    }
}
 
    if (valid)
    {
        alert("Log in was succesfull!")
        window.location = "timeline";
        return false;
    }
    var again = "tries";
    if (count ==1)
    {
        again = "try"
    }  
    if (count >= 1)
    {
        alert("Wrong password or username")
        count--;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Too many attempts");
        document.login.username.value = "You are now blocked";
        document.login.pass.value = "You are now blocked";
        document.login.username.disabled = true;
        document.login.password.disabled = true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

```css
html {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#333;}
body { background:#CCC; margin:0; }
#container { width:900px; margin:0 auto; background:#FFF; }
#header { width:100%; height:60px; border-bottom:1px solid #c7c7c7; background:#3f0b04; text-align:center; }
#header h1 {color:#e7c321; }
 
#logo { float:left; width:40px; height:40px; margin:10px; background:#CCC;}
#navbar { height:36px; clear:both; background-color:#e7c321; }
#navbar ul { margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none; }
#navbar ul li { padding:10px; float:left; }
#navbar ul li a { font size:12px; float:left; padding:0 0 0 20px; display:block; }
#banner { background:#3f0b04; heigth:120px; clear:both; padding:20px; text-align:center; color:#FFF; margin:10px 0 2px 0;}
#middle-column { float:left; width:858px; height:500px; border:1px solid #333; color:#000; background:#bcbab4; padding:20px; text-align:center; }
#login-logo {width:100%; ; height:200px; float:center;}
#login-form {float:center; width:175px; }
#submit {width:170px; float:center;}
#register {width:170px; float:center;}
 
#footer { padding:20px; clear:both; color:#FFF; background-color:#3f0b04; text-align:center; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"><img src="http://imgur.com/578H3e8.png"></img></div>
        <h1>BroCialize</h1>
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="url"></a></li>
                <li><a href="url"></a></li>
                <li><a href="url"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- CONTENT AREA -->
    <div id="content-area">
        <div id="banner">This site is Legen...wait for it...Dary</div>
        <div id="middle-column">
            <div id="login-logo"><img src="http://imgur.com/uelX4ie.png></img></div>
            <div id="login-form">
                <form method="POST">
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />
                    <br>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
                    <br>
                </form>
                <button id="submit">Log in</button>
                <br>
                <button id="register">Register</button>
            </div>
 
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--FOOTER -->
    <div id="footer">Copyright by BroCialize - 2016</div>
</div> <!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

Sorry if I am asking newbie questions, I am just looking for some help.
Thanks in advance,

-iWnB

Comment: I get it, as this is just for class, to show JavaScript knowlege, --  **BUT**  JavaScript is never to be used as an authentication method!  That they'd even require it in a class is silly, because there's no real-world application.  You need Server-Side authentication if you want a secure site.

Comment: You forgot to call the function.

Comment: I thought I called the function @ function validate ? How do I fix/do this ?

Answer (score 0):

As I see, the "document.login.username" won't be found, because there is no "login" named form on the site. So the function won't find where to check the username's value.

Comment: Your div's name is "login-form" wich contains your form. The form has only a method, but not an id wich is called after the document. Also you have to call the function within the <input>.

Comment: I made changes to <form method="POST" id="login-form"> and made the buttons into: <input type="button" id="submit">Log in</button> and <input type="button" id="register">Register</button> But now it's still not working & it messed up the css :3 ? Also the button code do they need to be in or outside the <form> ?

Comment: If you use "document.login.username", then you have to name your FORM to "login" because it contains the "username" textfield, which has the value you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

At least for now you have 2 major issues in your code.

First in the JS part you're using `document.login...` while there is no HTML element having `id="login"` (would likely be your `<form>`).
So currently you try to work on non existing elements.

On the other hand, directly related to your question

> when I press the login button it's not doing anything

1. In any case, when you press the button, the form it blongs to is submitted. This means that the url stated in the `action` attribute of the form is invoked.
2. But since you din't specify any `action` attribute, the default is to invoke the current page again.
   So yes, you don't see anything... but if you look at it carefully you'll notice your browser's tab quickly displaying it's waiting wheel, so attesting it invoked a page.

Following #1 you could have to write a dedicated PHP script (or include it in your current page) to do some job in response to the form submission.
But in the current case, what you want is merely to react to the button-press, in order to execute your `validate()` function.
To achieve it, there are 2 main ways:

1. The old fashion: add an `onclick` attribute to the `<button>` element. This is not recommended now, so I even not show you how to do it.
2. The modern fashion, which is to attach an event-listener to your button, like this:

   `document.onload = function() {
       document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', validate);
   }`

This piece of code must be added to your JS part, before or after the `validate()` function.

Comment: And where should I put the code, because I have never used it before and don't know what it does. Should I replace the function validate? or change the var username = document.login-form.username.value bu the code you just mentioned? Sorry for the dumb questions but I am just really confused by coding and this is the only course I need to be able to continue college.

Comment: @iWnb Sorry, I'd have been more precise. I edited my answer.

Comment: I am gonna try this out now, and don't apologize already awesome that people are willing to help imo :D

Comment: This is what I got now: http://pastebin.com/zkUG094h I don't know what I am doing or trying atm :(

Comment: @iWnb You put the additional code _inside_ your function, while it must be _before or after_ it! In other words, before or after the _entire_ function, including its declaration and block. BTW: note that I'll get off now, while I guess you'll encounter serveral other issues with your code. So 1) don't think you're abandoned :)  2) More likely, once your code will begin to work a little, first try to solve your issues by yourself, then post another, new, question with your new version.

Comment: Oke I put it before my function and still nothing

Comment: Ye i ll continue to try tomorrow as it's already 2am for me aswell